# Spring boot 2.6 pagination with Cassandra

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra

I need to implement pagination with Spring boot and Cassandra. I found cool solution [here](https://github.com/JSextonn/spring-cassandra-pagination-example)

However, it uses old version of Spring boot - `2.1.6.RELEASE`, mine is `2.6.4`.
The main difference in my case is when I call `pageRequest.getPagingState()` with old version, it returns `com.datastax.driver.core.PagingState` object which I can map to `String` and return to a client and vice versa: I can get this object from a String value.

But my version of Spring returns `java.nio.ByteBuffer` and I don't understand what I have to do with that.

Are there any ways to get `String` from this ByteBuffer or maybe other working ways to implement pagination?

P.S. I know about solution with iterator, but don't think that keeping all objects in memory is a good idea (in case I have millions of objects).

P.S.S. I also tried to get bytes from ByteBuffer using `byteBuffer.array()` but it throws exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That how it works in my case. Retrieving from `String`:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public Pageable test(@RequestParam Integer pageSize, @RequestParam String pagingState) {
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = com.datastax.oss.protocol.internal.util.Bytes.fromHexString(pagingState);
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, pageSize); // a page number might be any and the result depends only on paging state
    CassandraPageRequest pageRequest = CassandraPageRequest.of(pageable, byteBuffer);
    Slice<Test> all = repository.findAll(pageRequest1);
    return all.getPageable();
}
```

Mapping `ByteBuffer` to a `String`:

```
Slice<Test> tests = repository.findAll(pageRequest);
CassandraPageRequest cassandraPageRequest = (CassandraPageRequest) tests.getPageable();
ByteBuffer pagingState = cassandraPageRequest.getPagingState();
String pagingStateStr = com.datastax.oss.protocol.internal.util.Bytes.toHexString(pagingState);
```